# Turn detached coordinate values into linestring in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I have the following dataframe

```
id  x1              y1              x2              y2
0   431634.751688   4.581910e+06    431692.792776   4.581814e+06
1   431930.133825   4.581873e+06    431938.831274   4.581865e+06
2   431926.171004   4.581867e+06    431930.133825   4.581873e+06
3   431930.133825   4.581873e+06    431936.892345   4.581880e+06
```

The values (x1, y1) are the starting point coordinates, and (x2, y2) belong to the ending point.

How can I turn the single coordinates into linestrings?

Comment: You need to describe how those coordinates should form (a) inestring(a). What is their order. Which ones belong together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a linestring for each row, you can do the following:

```
In [1]: from shapely.geometry import LineString 

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,4), columns=['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
         x1        y1        x2        y2
0  0.866753  0.508888 -1.909955 -0.669491
1  0.190494 -0.985312 -0.680165 -1.126238

In [4]: df.apply(lambda row: LineString([(row.x1, row.y2), (row.x2, row.y2)]), axis=1)
Out[4]: 
0    LINESTRING (0.8667529205642079 -0.669490509579...
1    LINESTRING (0.1904941313773766 -1.126237639460...
dtype: object
```